# How do you change the dock icon for System Preferences app in MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, dock, icon, system-settings

all. As the title suggests, would appreciate some help into changing the dock icon for System Preferences app.

Obviously this would be easy for third party apps, and I've found a workaround for the Finder app, but have yet to see a solution for the System Preferences app.

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Apple.SE! Could you perhaps indicate what you've tried so far? I understand you have a method for the 3rd party applications and Finder, but why don't these methods work for System Preferences? What error are you getting?

Comment: So for 3rd party applications, Apple doesn't restrict your changing of their icons. However, for system-native applications, Apple has some restrictions. For example, the Finder app would require you to disable SIP to do so. However, I'm not sure what would be the case for the System Preferences app